# Excel UserForm Multiline Textbox truncates text

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform, multiline

I have a multi-line enables textbox placed within a Frame on a UserForm of an Excel VBA project.

MaxLength is set to 0.
IntegralHeight = True.
Wordwrap = True.
Vertical scrollbar is allowed.

During runtime, when I present the form, the textbox content is truncated after 440 chars. I can still enter more text, and the vertical scrollbar kicks in nicely, and even when I save the textbox content to a cell in a Worksheet - all text is saved fine.

During design time, I am able to set the Text property (default control value) to as many chars as I want, and they do display correctly during design time, but during runtime - it is truncated in presentation (still complete in design time).

Tried setting MaxLength to 10,000 - no help.

On that project I have other forms with multi-line text boxes where this behavior is not experienced - all work fine.

Any idea why this happens?

Excel 2016 with latest updates, on Windows 10.

Comment: If you have other textboxes which behave correctly, try copying one of those to the desired position and renaming it. There may be some other setting which is lingering in your current textbox which is causing this unexpected behaviour.

Comment: You could check if you set the `.MaxLength` or `.Width` property somewhere in code where you don't suspect it. In addition you could set the `.Width` property explicitly and do some debugging where the redimensioning takes place :-)

Comment: @Chris - tried that, same behavior. Found out another textbox on that same form (in another frame) is also truncating after 440 chars...

Comment: @T.M. Found no use of .MaxLength in the code, and no .Width applied to this control. The Width property is set to 480, but I don't think it has anything to do with the text inside the control, WrapText is True...

Comment: Are you able to share the workbook and post a link here? Strip down any actual information contained, to make a minimal verifiable example. A barebones workbook with a functional userform displaying the behaviour described.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my Excel 2016 with latest updates on Windows 10 and it was working correctly.

What you can do is delete the userform and create a new fresh userform and try doing it there. Maybe some sort of coding issues is in that userform, so it is recommended to create a fresh one.

If have any more doubt, you can ask me :)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for offering advise.

I found the issue.

I have a generic function for formatting controls on forms based on a table holding formatting strings. Applying a "General" formatting to this multi-line textbox (as the default for missing formatting entry in the table) somehow caused this truncation.

I now skip formatting controls if no entry found in the table altogether.

To reproduce:

On a clean Workbook, create a UserForm1, add a single multiline textbox, with vertical scrollbar, name it "txtTest".

Copy this as the Init event of the form:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.txtTest.Value = "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book. It usually begins with: " & Chr(10) & _
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
        "The purpose of lorem ipsum is to create a natural looking block of text (sentence, paragraph, page, etc.) that doesn't distract from the layout. A practice not without controversy, laying out pages with meaningless filler text can be very useful when the focus is meant to be on design, not content. " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
        "The passage experienced a surge in popularity during the 1960s when Letraset used it on their dry-transfer sheets, and again during the 90s as desktop publishers bundled the text with their software. Today it's seen all around the web; on templates, websites, and stock designs. Use our generator to get your own, or read on for the authoritative history of lorem ipsum."

    Me.txtTest.Value = Format(Me.txtTest.Value, "General")
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution. BTW it would be helpful for readers trying to reproduce the issue, if you could edit a code example (*excerpt*) of the mentioned generic function as it apparently hid direct `.Width` assignments or covered direct referencing.

Comment: @T.M. no .Width was involved, only formatting of the control text using VBA Format function. Something like: frm.txtComments.value = Format(frm.txtComments.value, "General"). - that caused the truncation. If you ask me - it's an Excel bug. I just avoid formatting this textbox at all now.

Comment: @T.M. I added instructions to reproduce up here in my answer.

Comment: Apparently there seems to be no other remedy than to do without `Format` (possibly no great loss  for texts like this one). *BTW in my vers. 2010 I get text truncated already at 255 characters (a former cell limitation).*